Linux & OpenDocument Format - How to compress directory of XML files to ODF in the command line?
I am trying to experiment with ODF files, specifically .ods files. The directory I am working with is an unzipped .ods file made with LibreOffice, and all I am trying to do is recompress it.
I have tried using the following commands:

zip -Z deflate test_new.ods -r test1/
tar -czvf test_new.ods test1/
gzip -cr test1/* > test_new.ods
gzip -cr test1 > test_new.ods

I was expecting to open test_new.ods with LibreOffice and it display the cells that I have added. Instead I either get an error saying the file is corrupted or it displaying each XML document's content instead of the data I added to the cells.

UPDATE:
I read this answer but the problem is the same error of corruption by LibreOffice is still happening

You need to be zipping from inside the directory, not outside of it, where the latter would put test1/ before every file name. You also need to zip mimetype first, with no compression, using -0, and then zip the remaining files, excluding mimetype.
tar and gzip have nothing to with this. You do not need to use -Z.
cd test1
zip -X -0 ../test_new.ods mimetype
zip -X -r ../test_new.ods * -x mimetype
cd ..

